# Entity Framework - Same Database Accessed/Developed from Multiple Websites?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, migration, code-first

I have the main website that uses a database to store and access user accounts. I'm using EF to manage the schema. I also defined site-specific POCOs and have migrated them to the database.

Now, what if I want a separate website, for example, a resource server (Web API) that would expose (with authorization) the same data set up on the main website?

- Do I create the same POCOs and derived DbContext on the resource server again? That seems like duplicating work, though.
- What if I wanted to create new POCOs on the resource server and reflect them onto that same database? Wouldn't that conflict with the current migration (which is saved on the database), then subsequently mess up the EF setup on the main website?

I've seen the suggestion of putting the POCOs and DbContexts in a library and have multiple projects reference that same library. This seems viable, however I'd have to hard-code the connection string, which seems dirty to me.

I'm starting to think that EF is probably not recommended for this kind of setup. It seems like a database-first approach plays better here - though I would have to manually reedit the data contexts (most likely, LINQ-SQL) for every database schema change.

Are there any lesser-known capabilities, facts, practices, etc., for/about EF that would help in this situation?

Comment: The library is definitely way to go and you don't need to hardcode connection string. Connection string still lives in configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can avoid duplication by having one API serving both sites and have resources version for each if needed. On the other hand, if you choose reuse and add approach, creating additional EF code-first entities should not interfere with other site data layer if modeled and mapped carefully. DbContext connection string does not have to be hard-coded.